# java Optional interface methods: Ambiguous method reference

Tags: java, java-stream

I've coded this:

```
this.referenceService.get(id)
    .map(Reference::hashCode)
    .map(Integer::toString);
```

I'm getting this compilation error:

> Ambiguous method reference: both toString() and toString(int) from the type Integer are eligible

How could I work around this?

Comment: what are `referenceService` and the `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possible solutions:

Replace it with a lambda:

```
this.referenceService.get(id)
    .map(ref-> Integer.toString(ref.hashCode()));
```

use [Objects.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)

```
this.referenceService.get(id)
    .map(Reference::hashCode)
    .map(Objects::toString); // this will cal toString method on you hash
```

Write your own method:

```
this.referenceService.get(id)
    .map(this::toHashString);

private Strign toHashString(Reference ref) {
  return Integer.toString(ref.hashCode());
}
```

Comment: @Eran Thank you, I have edited my response.

Comment: Could I chain `.map(Objects::toString(Reference::hashCode))`?

Comment: No, to a Map you can pass a single method reference. (Objects::toString(...)) is an invalid method reference. Will not compile. But you can write your own method, and reference it. I have updated my answer, please check it.